# Covariant derivative of a vector field along a curve in coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I was reading about Riemannian Geometry here: [https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/leeriemm.pdf](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/leeriemm.pdf)

Could anybody explain the second equality of 4.10. on page 57? Why is there a k as an index for the first V? Shouldn't there be a j? Can anybody show me all the steps? I tried doing it but I never arrive at the desired result. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author is just replacing $\dot{V}^j(t_0)\,\partial_j$ in the first line by $\dot{V}^k(t_0)\,\partial_k$ in the second line. Since we're summing over the index, you can use any letter you wish for it (it's a so-called *dummy* variable). The reason the author changes it from $j$ to $k$ is because in the second line, the second term contains a (dummy) $k$ index, and he wishes to factor out the $\partial_k$ from both terms.